# C++ library to read encrypted PDF documents that runs on iOS and Android

Tags: android, c++, ios, pdf-viewer, flutter

I am using Flutter and a plugin to read the encrypted pages which depend on Apache PDFBox, a Java library, but they are slow in rendering the all pages for phones with less RAM; one way is to decrypt all the pages on separate threads and then show the pages as stream as grid view.

That's why I wanted to ask if there is any C++ library (runs on both Android and iOS) that can return the decrypted pages faster and in the form of a stream of decrypted pages or pages till the given index. This will improve the rendering and loading time of pages on low-end devices.

Comment: The [LEADTOOLS PDF SDK Libraries](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/pdf) work on multiple platforms, including iOS and Android. (Disclosure: I work for the SDK's vendor).  However, the native code for iOS is not the same as the native code for Android, so if you want to use the same code to load encrypted PDF on both platforms, it's better to use C#, since the SDK's .NET classes allow you to use the same code for both operating systems. If you'd like to try it, you can download a free evaluation edition [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).